# Convert currency with symbol to decimal

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, cultureinfo

I have a text box which displays the currency values like `250.00 €,$1,000.00 ,£100.00` etc

I have culture created based on the currency symbol.

```
  var culture = new CultureInfo(symbol); //symbol may be en-US,en-GB etc..
  culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
```

and doing something like below at the moment

```
decimal amount;    
decimal.TryParse(txtAmount.Text, NumberStyles.Any, _culture, out rate);
```

which works fine.

I have issue with Swedish Kroner when the amount is >1000 as it formats the currency.

i.e.

when enter 100 it become 100.00 kr  and works fine

when enter 1000 it 1.000.00 kr and it get failed and amount become 0

Any idea of getting around this?

Comment: What part of your code turns 1000 to **1.000.00 kr**?  That's the part that needs to be corrected, since it should be **1.000,00 kr**.

Comment: You could remove every occurance of the '.' except the last one, before converting. Quick and very dirty ;-)

Comment: How do you create `_culture`?

Comment: @DanielGimenez :doing  `txtAmount.Text = rate.ToString("c2", _culture);` at the moment

Comment: @petelids: These is no issue with culture it works fine, it been created based in associated currency code. in this case  `new CultureInfo("sv-SE")`

Comment: Are you sure - I've just tested that and it parses it without issue. `string test = "1.000.00 kr";
            CultureInfo _culture = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");
            decimal rate;
            decimal.TryParse(test, NumberStyles.Any, _culture, out rate);//rate=100000`

Comment: When I use "sv-SE" and do a `toString()`, the number I get back is **1.000,00 kr**, not **1.000.00 kr**.

Comment: @petelids => that result is wrong, he wants 1000 back, not 100000.  It's not using the correct decimal point.

Comment: @DanielGimenez - yes, you're right. Given the input 1.000,00 the result is 1000. I can repro this if I set `_culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";` - has that setting got the wrong value?

Comment: I do `CurrencyDecimalSeparator = "."` when creating the culture

Comment: Well the problem is that the cultureInfo on your server is wrong when you're doing `rate.ToString("c2", _culture);`.  You shouldn't have to set `CurrencyDecimalSeparator ` at all.  I would update your server.

Comment: That's the issue then I think. Your `CurrencyDecimalSeparator` and `NumberGroupSeparator` will both be `.`.

Comment: @huMptyduMpty does it still work even if the decimal is correctly a **,**?

Comment: @DanielGimenez: yes, tested with other currency and works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was all about creating the culture.

As DanielGimenez pointed out, I removed the `NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = "."`  and all works fine

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @PaulRoub: Sorry, what you mean by *Complete answers* ?

Comment: It's boilerplate text from the SO Review tools. In hindsight, I was too quick on the trigger here. Leaving the comment up only so that yours still makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the culture like this:-

```
CultureInfo sw= new CultureInfo("sv-SE");
sw = (CultureInfo)sw.Clone();
sw.NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern = 3;
sw.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 3;
```

and then

```
var rate = 123.45M;
txtAmount.Text = rate.ToString("C", sw);
```

Output

```
123,45 kr
```